# Why is paste event value delayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/yLo5hm81/

```
$('#mytext').on('paste keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('hello', e.type, this.value)
})
```

When I paste, it's always behind. So pasting a value initially returns empty string. Pasting again returns what I originally pasted.

Any workaround?

**Edit** You must right click and paste from context menu. Reproduced in Chrome & FF

Comment: It's fine for me. Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Firefox, and updated steps :)

Comment: paste events fire before the paste changes the value so that it can be cancelled from the event

Comment: It works if you just use `$('#mytext').on('paste', function(e) {...}`, did you specifically need the keyup?

Comment: @IanGabes yeah cause it's live search so just wanted to handle the paste and keyup cases, and change doesn't work til blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `input` event for all your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/yLo5hm81/3/

```
$('#mytext').on('input', function(e) {
    console.log(this.value);
})
```

Comment: Ah damn that's the one I couldn't remember that was so obvious. I remembered `propertychange` and then remembered that was just IE ha